# Creating an Array for cellForRowAtIndexPath with Other Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have an indexed `tableView` that displays a list of songs from the user's iPod library.  This is how I currently get the song titles, which causes **scrolling to be very slow**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell.textLabel.text= [self titleForRow:indexPath];  //getting cell content
}
```

...which calls these methods:

```
-(NSString *)titleForRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{

    NSMutableArray* rowArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    rowArray=[self getArrayOfRowsForSection:indexpath.section];
    NSString *titleToBeDisplayed=[rowArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    return titleToBeDisplayed;

}

-(NSMutableArray *)getArrayOfRowsForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *rowTitle;
    NSString *sectionTitle;
    NSMutableArray *rowContainer=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

    for (int i=0; i<self.alphabetArray.count; i++)
    {
        if (section==i)   // check for right section
        {
            sectionTitle= [self.alphabetArray objectAtIndex:i];  //getting section title
            for (MPMediaItem *song in songs)
            {
                NSString *title = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
                rowTitle= [title substringToIndex:1];  //modifying the statement to its first alphabet
                if ([rowTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitle])  //checking if modified statement is same as section title
                {
                    [rowContainer addObject:title];  //adding the row contents of a particular section in array
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rowContainer;
}
```

The problem is: for each `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I am calling these methods and creating these arrays **for each cell**.  So I need to create a separate array and simply call the `objectAtIndex` from that array.

This is what I have tried so far: created an `NSMutableArray *newArray`, and the following method:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getNewArray:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *rowTitle;
    NSString *sectionTitle;

    for (int i=0; i<self.alphabetArray.count; i++)
    {
        if (section==i)   // check for right section
        {
            sectionTitle= [self.alphabetArray objectAtIndex:i];  //getting section title
            for (MPMediaItem *song in songs)
            {
                NSString *title = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
                rowTitle= [title substringToIndex:1];  //modifying the statement to its first alphabet
                if ([rowTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitle])  //checking if modified statement is same as section title
                {
                    [newArray addObject:title];  //adding the row contents of a particular section in array
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

But this seems very wrong and I'm really confused on how to solve this.  I have no clue how to create a separate array with these methods, populating `newArray` with the song titles, and I've searched Google for quite some time now and I can't find anything that would help me.

Could somebody point me in the right direction, or please show me how I'd creat newArray?  [I've attached my tableView data source here](http://goo.gl/600dVI). Thanks.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add what your data source looks like (your alphabet array).  You have a lot of code which looks like it is searching through your data source and creating a new data source, all so you can create a cell.  Cleaning that up would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table View cells are enqueued and dequeued in a serial manner. Leveraging this ability you should expect that only sections change in less frequency. You can use static variables to exempt the fetching of a section. Look at my code

```
-(NSString *)titleForRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{
    static NSIndexPath *funIndexPath;
    static NSMutableArray *funSectionArray;
    if (!funIndexPath || funIdexpath.section != indexpath.section) {
        funIndexPath = indexpath;
        funSectionArray = [self getArrayOfRowsForSection:indexpath.section];
    }
    rowArray = funSectionArray;
    NSString *titleToBeDisplayed = [rowArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    return titleToBeDisplayed;
}
```

This is the first optimisation possible.

When I look at your fetching results array, some things are not clear. Why are you iterating to check `section == i`. You can just substitute `section` for `i` in your code.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getNewArray:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *rowTitle;
    NSString *sectionTitle;

    sectionTitle = [self.alphabetArray objectAtIndex:section];  //getting section title
        for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
            NSString *title = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            rowTitle= [title substringToIndex:1];  //modifying the statement to its first alphabet
            if ([rowTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitle])  //checking if modified statement is same as section title
            {
                [newArray addObject:title];  //adding the row contents of a particular section in array
            }
        }
    return newArray;
}
```

Its still not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Going against my own answer, I suggest you that you do not compute you data for display during view rendering time. You need to create the cells as fast as possible. Why not create a property or an iVar (like @bauerMusic is Suggesting) and compute the date in `viewDidLoad` or declare a custom function which will reload your property (possible an `Array` or `Dictionary`) and while rendering the UI, just set the values (in you `viewForIndexPath`)?

You can use an array of two level depth to store for maintaining sections and rows. i.e. Level 1 - Sections and Array of rows, Level 2 - row.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  In `getNewArray` I was trying to create a new array with all my song titles so I could only load it once and then simply refer to a single array in `cellForRow`.  I apologize for being unclear.  As I commented on Hot Licks' and bauerMusic's answers, I'm confused as to how to create and add the song titles to an @property NSMutableDictionary with these methods.  :S

Answer (score 0):

The center of it all is:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self titleForRow:indexPath];
```

Now, what you're actually using are `NSString`. Simple. Instead, you're creating a new array for each cell each call??
Why not have **one** array, say an NSMutableArray. Have it as a `@property` or local iVar.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *rowArray;


// Instantiate in -viewDidLoad
rowArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // Much more elegant IMHO
```

Now call a method that do all the content loading, but do it **ONCE**. You can always call it again to refresh.

Something like:

```
// In -viewDidLoad
rowArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[self loadArrayContent];
```

Then, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should only be using your preloaded `rowArray` and simply pulling `NSString` titles from it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looking at Hot Licks' answer I should perhaps add this information in an @property NSMutableDictionary.  How would I do this?  This was actually my original question but I was definitely unclear (I apologize).  I tried to add all the song titles in my `getNewArray` method but it failed miserably.  How do I add all the titles to a `@property NSMutableDictionary` with these methods, so it keeps my indexing?  :S

Comment: There are some conceptually differences, but it's important to note that you still need an `Array`, only that array is in an `NSDictionary`. There is a literal shortcut `@{@"key":@"value"}`, otherwise, use `setObject:forKey:`. Ex: `[myDictionary setObject:myArray forKey:@"Song List"];` Here's the full ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

My general way to handle a table view is to create (during table view setup) an NSMutableArray for the rows (anchored in the data source object).  Each entry in the array is an NSMutableDictionary that is "primed" with the basic stuff for the row, and if more info needs to be developed to display the row, that is cached in the dictionary.  (Where there are multiple sections I use an array of sections containing arrays of rows.)

What I might do for a play list is initialize the array with empty dictionaries, then, as one scrolls, access each play list element and cache it in the dictionary.

In fact, if one really wanted, updating the dictionary could be done via a background task (with appropriate locking) so that scroll speed wouldn't be hampered by the lookup operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my original question was a bit unclear as I was asking how to actually add all the titles to a new array, as I tried to do so in `getNewArray` in my OP, but it went horribly wrong.  How would I add all the song titles to an `@property NSMutableDictionary` with these methods. :S

Comment: @user3127576 -- Create an NSMutableArray.  Populate it either with NSMutableDictionary (as I suggest above) or NSNull (plain-Jane version) objects to be the right size.  Update the array as you reference each row.  It's easy to test whether a given array element has already been updated.